# Deploy a Cloud Services (extended support) using New-AzCloudService

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I'm trying to understand how to deploy an Azure Cloud Services (extended support) using the powershell command `New-AzCloudService`.
I already deployed the cloud service using Visual Studio and everything went well, but when I try to deploy it using the following command

```
New-AzCloudService 
-Name $ServiceName 
-ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName 
-Location $Location 
-ConfigurationFile $CscfgFilePath 
-DefinitionFile $CsdefFilePath 
-PackageFile $CspkgFilePath 
-StorageAccount $StorageAccount
```

I receive the error below:

```
A Cloud Service resource with name: <service_name> already exists in Resource Group: 
<resource_group_name>. Please try another name.
```

Looking at the `New-AzCloudService` documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.cloudservice/new-azcloudservice?view=azps-8.3.0) it states: `Create or update a cloud service`.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check whether the cloud service (one which you are trying to create) is already existed in your environment using `Get-AzureRmResourceProvider` or `Get-AzureRmResource` because there might be a chance of having the same service name with other subscriptions/regions.

Comment: Have you tried using Update-AzCloudService? The docs could be messed up, there. :/  (I agree that, with docs as written, the error message doesn't make much sense. I wonder if New maps to POST and Update maps to PUT. REST docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/cloud-services/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP suggest PUT is preferred.)

Answer (score 0):

because you have already deployed a cloud service use the same name in the Resource Group.
you need delete the exists one or change another cloud service name